# R: How to convert matrix of class ngTMatrix into dgCMatrix, and plot using image function.

Tags: r, image, sparse-matrix

I create a sparseMatrix, save it to a MatrixMarket format using writeMM - the sparse matrix automatically changes to a ngTMatrix class (from dgCMatrix). I load it back using readMM and plot the matrix. Everything is fine except that I cannot using the simple xlim, ylim to control the axis. If I am currently interested only in being able to control the axes, what would be the solution?

A sample code

```
a = sparseMatrix(i=c(1,2,3),j=c(9,5,7),x=1)
image(a,ylim=c(0,4))   # ylim Works!

writeMM(a,'test.mtx')
b = readMM('test.mtx')   #b now belongs to ngTMatrix class
image(b,ylim=c(0,4))   # ylim does not work !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dgCMatrix` is a standard numeric matrix ([description](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html)), while `ngTMatrix` is a binary TRUE/FALSE, logical matrix ([description](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nsparseMatrix-classes.html))

```
> print(a)
3 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . . . . . 1
[2,] . . . . 1 . . . .
[3,] . . . . . . 1 . .

> print(b)
3 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "ngTMatrix"

[1,] . . . . . . . . |
[2,] . . . . | . . . .
[3,] . . . . . . | . .
```

**Multiply by 1 to coerce the logical matrix into numeric, and the plotting will work:**

```
> print(b*1)
3 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . . . . . 1
[2,] . . . . 1 . . . .
[3,] . . . . . . 1 . .

> image(b*1, ylim=c(0,4))
```

Alternatively, you can use `as()` function, as illustrated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664448/in-r-how-do-i-load-a-matrix-market-formated-sparse-matrix-into-a-dgcmatrix).

Comment: Works!. However, I cannot use as() to convert to dgCMatrix (R Error: no method or default for coercing “ngTMatrix” to “dgCMatrix”).

Comment: It's easier to multiply by 1, since there is no single step conversion available; except `as(as(b,"ngCMatrix"),"dgCMatrix")`

Comment: This is not too bad either, but multiplying by 1 is definitely an easier option.